# How to disable eslint during emergency?

Tags: webpack, eslint

During development, eslint is great for writing that perfect javascript code.

But consider this scenario, that you are demo-ing your work. And you ran `npm run dev` and eslint produces error due to some syntax. I could go on and debug the code and hope that it's only a silly space or extra lines somewhere.

Or I can disable eslint for a moment and move on.

I have tried to comment out the `.eslintrc.js` file or pass in values like `npm run dev --no-eslintrc`. Obviously they are not the solution.

Does anyone know how to disable eslint on a webpack project during emergencies like this? Preferably a command line solution?

Comment: Modify your package.json to have `"start": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts start",` --https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821078/disable-eslint-that-create-react-app-provides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about trying to comment out the eslint loader inside your webpack config?
source: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/73

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I was hoping to get a command line solution. But this will work too