# Disable ESLint that create-react-app provides

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, create-react-app

[`create-react-app` v3.0.0 is out](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). It supports TypeScript linting internally. (That's nice!) I think I understand the situation where TSLint is on, and am planning to replace it with ESLint, but it is not right now.

How to disable that linting step in `react-scripts start`?

`/* eslint-disable */` and others are not the ones I'm looking for.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

As of `react-scripts` v4.0.2, you can now opt out of ESLint with an environment variable. You can do this by adding it to your `.env` file, or by prefixing your scripts in your package.json file.

For example in `.env`:

```
DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true
```

Or in your package.json:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts start",
    "build": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts build",
    "test": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts test"
  }
}
```

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/10170

Comment: The `.env` solution still works but the `package.json` one.

Comment: When adding in package.json I am getting this error - 'DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: If you're getting that error (like if you try to run it from Windows), try this instead:
`"start": "set DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true && react-scripts start",`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I have a shared eslint config in my monorepo and it had a conflict with CRA eslint config, disabling it with the `.env` variable saved my life.

Answer (score 78):

You could set EXTEND_ESLINT environment variable to `true`, for example in `.env` file:

```
EXTEND_ESLINT=true
```

Now you can extend eslint configuration in your `package.json` file:

```
...
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off"
    }
  },
...
```

To disable eslint you could add a file `.eslintignore` with the content:

```
*
```

See documentation for details: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config

Comment: This doesnt disable eslint. This simply exclude eslint to all files. Not technically the same.

Answer (score 25):

You can disable [eslint](/questions/tagged/eslint) (and override other configurations) using [Craco](https://github.com/sharegate/craco).

It takes 4 changes:

1. `npm install @craco/craco --save`
2. create `craco.config.js` (in the same folder as is package.json)
3. populate `craco.config.js` with:

```
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    enable: false,
  },
};
```

Finally, replace `react-script` with `craco` in your `package.json` scripts, i.e.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "craco build",
  "start": "craco start",
}
```

This will disable ESLint. Refer to [Craco documentation](https://github.com/sharegate/craco) for examples how to extend ESLint configuration.

Answer (score 8):

### step 1

create `.env` file in your project root if its not there and add this line to it

```
EXTEND_ESLINT=true
```

### Step 2

add `.eslintrc.js` to your project root with following content

```
module.exports = {
  "extends": ["react-app"],
  "rules": {
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.js?(x)"],
      "rules": {
// ******** add ignore rules here *********
        "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
        "react/display-name": "off",
        "react/prop-types": "off",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

note that `override > rules` section: add rules with "off" flag to disable them.

Answer (score 5):

My workaround without ejecting:

1. Use an environment variable in *.eslintrc.js* like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "extends": process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_DISABLE_ESLINT ? [] : [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:import/errors",
      "plugin:import/warnings",
      "plugin:json/recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended",
    ],
    "rules": process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_DISABLE_ESLINT ? {} : {
      // ...rules for production CI
    }
}
```

2. Set the variable in start script in **package.json**:

```
{
      "scripts": {
          "eslint:disable": "REACT_APP_DEV_DISABLE_ESLINT=true",
          "start": "npm run eslint:disable  react-scripts start"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First ensure `EXTEND_ESLINT` environment variable is set to true. It can be set in `.env` file.

For Typescript, further rules should be added in overrides array, as example below:

```
{
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["react-app"],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["**/*.ts?(x)"],
        "rules": {
          "eqeqeq": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Something interesting that happened to me is that although this hid the one I wanted, it also produced new ones that were never before seen.

Answer (score 2):

My workaround:

Add a .eslintignore file:

```
*
```

and run eslint with `--no-ignore`. So you are able to setup your own eslint. If you need a ignore file you can define it with `--ignore-path` instead of using the `--no-ignore` option.

Answer (score 1):

In package.json you can find the eslintConfig rule, which might have some content already, like this:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
]
},
```

Here you can disable the rules you want to disable:

```
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
],
"rules": {
  "no-unused-vars": "off"
}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to `eject` `react-scripts` - by running `yarn eject` / `npm run eject` - and turn off `eslint` in `webpack` config file manually.

Beware though that ejecting should not be done lightly and other options should be considered before ejecting. Please read [Don’t eject your Create React App](https://medium.com/curated-by-versett/dont-eject-your-create-react-app-b123c5247741) to gain some understanding of what it means and perhaps some reason's why you shouldn't

Please take a look at this fork: [create-react-app closer look](https://github.com/pawel-schmidt/cra_closer_look), especially at `eject-tic_tac_toe` directory, where you have `scripts/start.js` - the script where the magic happens after `yarn start` / `npm start` - and `config/webpack.config.dev.js` - where you have webpack's config, used in `start.js`. This is the part you can be interested in to edit:

```js
// …
module.exports = {
  // …
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: paths.appSrc,
      }
    ]
  }
  // …
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Might you need just to disable it for compilation but not to check I console?

then, either replace the `start` script or use a new one, e.g. `start-force`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start-force": "ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true react-scripts start",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure ESLint to disable linting for specific files or directories. In your .eslintrc.js or .eslintrc.json file, you can add or modify the "ignorePatterns" property to specify the files or directories you want to exclude from linting. In my case I exclude src folder.

```
    {
    "ignorePatterns": ["src/"],
    // ...
    }
```