# Where do I type the --fix option in heroku?

Tags: heroku

My app failed to deploy and this popped up in the logs:
11 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
I was wondering where would I type in this command.

Comment: Looks like an eslint error. I’m guessing you’re trying to deploy an app made with create react app? They fail the build on eslint errors in production.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66996518/4722345

Comment: I’m marking this as needing more details for now - I suggest including the full build output if you don’t want the question to be closed.