# 'React' must be in scope when using JSX but I do not use ESLint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have read in [react docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#eslint) and here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope) that for my existing error: `'React' must be in scope when using JSX` I should disable some ESLint things but I have unistalled ESLint completely from VSCode and I still get the error.

I created a simple react app using `create react app` with `typescript` and `react-router-dom`. React is v.17+

Here is my code:

**src/index.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**src/App.tsx**

```
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "views/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={Home} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**src/views/Home.tsx**

```
const Home = () => {
  return <div>Home</div>;
};

export default Home;
```

If I import `import React from "react";` on top of `App.tsx` and `Home.tsx` then it compiles without a problem. But I am not satisfied with that solution since I am using React v.17+

Comment: did you used `npx create react app` ?

Comment: @shubhamjha Yes, like in their doc explained ```npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript```

Answer (score 2):

Eslint is bundled into create react app, you would need to eject and disable the rule manually if you want it to disappear.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer gave me the right guide. I researched CRA a bit and also found this useful answer about disabling anything: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66719992/7335848 . Somehow in ```package.json``` my version of ```react-scripts``` was changed to ```^3.0.1```. I created a new CRA app and now it is ```v5.0.0```, so the problems seem to be disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is the dependencies of Creact React App. If you eject your CRA app, you can see this list in Package.json. As you can see below, Eslint is in it! So even though you uninstalled eslint from plugin, it's still working behind CRA app. If you want eslint off, you should eject your CRA App and uninstall it but you should know you can't wrap ejected CRA App again and it's too difficult to maintain ejected CRA files. So, my answer is you should put import React from 'react' to all files or you should build your own React project with Webpack, babel.. etc but you know it takes learning time.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.3",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.8",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",
    "bfj": "^7.0.2",
    "browserslist": "^4.18.1",
    "camelcase": "^6.2.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.3",
    "jest-resolve": "^27.4.2",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^1.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "postcss-normalize": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.0.1",
    "prompts": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-refresh": "^0.11.0",
    "resolve": "^1.20.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.3.0",
    "semver": "^7.3.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.64.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^4.0.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1"
  },  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but you don't have to eject. Here is a useful answer from ```v4.0.2``` how disable anything: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66719992/7335848 and the official docs about custom environment variables https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/