# Failed to load plugin 'jsx-a11y' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app': Unexpected token =

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, jsx-a11y

Just got this error from today, I have config in package.json file:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ]
},
```

I have not changed that file for ages, it was fine before today. Anyone has idea? Thanks!

Just try to compile frontend components css, js files etc. But failed to compile from today.

Comment: Same thing here. Starting yesterday, our build is suddenly failing. We didn't change anything. We have the basic RCA eslint setup also, created by RCA and untouched since.

"eslintConfig": { "extends": "react-app" },

Answer (score 6):

In my case, we have a React app created with Create React App (CRA) back in 2019.
CRA automatically gave us ESLint enabled by default, and lint was ran as part of 'react-scripts build'. Our code for this app hasn't changed since early 2020.

Now something has changed somewhere, and ESLint gave us this "unexpected token" regarding 'jsx-a11y'. 'React-scripts build' failed with our build server having Node 10.x version.

Updating Node is one solution, as mentioned by previous answer.
But in our case build server is using Node 10.6, managed by other team. I cannot update Node there. I needed to get past this issue while still using Node 10.6.

My quick solution was to disable the CRA-provided ESLint so it's not executed as part of build, and to add ESLint manually so I can run it on-demand within my dev environment. (I also actually downgraded Node on my laptop to match Node version 10.6. used by build server, so I'll catch these more easily in the future.)

Few resources I found useful and combined from there:
[Disable ESLint that create-react-app provides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821078/disable-eslint-that-create-react-app-provides) , https://andrebnassis.medium.com/setting-eslint-on-a-react-typescript-project-2021-1190a43ffba

Comment: This answer saved me today. The exact same situation for me. A "Create React App" back in 2019/20 suddentdy failing on deploy. Much appreciated!

I need to schedule in some time to upate this app so this sort of thing does not happen again :-(

Comment: Updating node worked in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I think i finally realized what the issue is, i was running node 10.x version while the required node version was 14.x. upgraded my node version and all resolved

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer and easy solution, when you have possibility to update Node. In my case it was not possible to update Node (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

You must install the module eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y.

Type...

```bash
npm install eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
```

and press enter.

After install it will work.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer. Much better than the disabling lint or updating node version.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be due to the ES-lint.

I checked my package.json file and looked for the following code snippet.

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ]
},
```

Not the best solution but removing this part of the code from package.json worked for me.
(ps we can install any linter later on)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to the version of node that was specified in my project's "package.json" fixed this for me. You can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to change node versions.